# Customising Cabal libraries (I think?)

Tags: haskell, cabal

Perhaps it's just better to describe my problem.

I'm developing a Haskell library. But part of the library is written in C, and another part actually in raw LLVM. To actually get GHC to spit out the code I want I have to follow this process:

1. Run `ghc -emit-llvm` on both the code that uses the Haskell module and the "Main" module.
2. Run `clang -emit-llvm` on the C file
3. Now I've got three `.ll` files from above. I add the part of the library I've handwritten in raw LLVM and `llvm-link` these into one `.ll` file.
4. I then run LLVM's `opt` on the linked file.
5. Lastly, I feed the LLVM bitcode fileback into GHC (which pleasantly accepts it) and produces an executable.

This process (with appropriate optimisation settings of course) seems to be the only way I can inline code from C, removing the function call overhead. Since many of these C functions are very small this is significant.

Anyway, I want to be able to distribute the library and for users to be able to use it as painlessly as possible, whilst still gaining the optimisations from the process above. I understand it's going to be a bit more of a pain than an ordinary library (for example, you're forced to compile via LLVM) but as *painlessly* as possible is what I'm looking for advice for.

Any guidance will be appreciated, I don't expect a step by step answer because I think it will be complex, but just some ideas would be helpful.

Comment: You can probably coax cabal into getting to to step 1 almost by itself by passing the correct ghc-options; for the rest you will probably have to write your own `postBuildHook`. You probably already have a bash script or the like to do this - your hook can just call this script. There isn't much finesse at this level, I think - cabal hooks are a big hammer.